# Rows.Scan fails with Scanner objects with the github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql driver

Tags: mysql, go

I am trying to use Scanner objects in my Go application to query the database server.  I have no problems with Microsoft SQL Server, but found that If I use scanner objects with `Rows.Scan` to query MySQL, the `src` argument is a `[]uint8` for all types.

My table is

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS fruits (
        id BIGINT(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        name VARCHAR(45),
        year SMALLINT,
        amount INT,
        price FLOAT(23),
        PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

Here is my code

```golang
type Scanner struct {
        FieldName string
}

func (s *Scanner) Scan(src any) error {
        fmt.Printf("FieldName: %s, src: type=%[2]T value=%[2]v", s.FieldName, src)
        return nil
}

// prepare to query
id_scanner := &Scanner{"Id"}
name_scanner := &Scanner{"Name"}
year_scanner := &Scanner{"Year"}
amount_scanner := &Scanner{"Amount"}
price_scanner := &Scanner{"Price"}

// query single row
row := db.QueryRow("select * from fruits where id=?", 1)
err := row.Scan(id_scanner, name_scanner, year_scanner, amount_scanner, price_scanner)
```

The `err` is `nil` and the output looks very nice, such as

```
FieldName: Id, src: type=int64 value=1
FieldName: Name, src: type=[]uint8 value=[97 112 112 108 101]
FieldName: Year, src: type=int64 value=1965
FieldName: Amount, src: type=int64 value=123
FieldName: Price, src: type=float32 value=7.55
```

This shows that `Row.Scan` works with Scanner objects. However, `Rows.Scan` fails:

```golang
rows, err := db.Query("select * from fruits;")
// err is nil
defer rows.Close()
for rows.Next() {
        err := rows.Scan(id_scanner, name_scanner, year_scanner, amount_scanner, price_scanner)
        // err is nil, but output is wrong
}
```

Running against the mysql:8..0.31 docker image, the output is different:

```
FieldName: Id, src: type=[]uint8 value=[49]
FieldName: Name, src: type=[]uint8 value=[97 112 112 108 101]
FieldName: Year, src: type=[]uint8 value=[49 57 54 53]
FieldName: Amount, src: type=[]uint8 value=[49 50 51]
FieldName: Price, src: type=[]uint8 value=[55 46 53 53]
```

- For the `Id` field, the value `[49]` is the string "1".
- For the `Name` field, the value `[97 112 112 108 101]` is string "apple".
- For the `Year` field, the value `[49 57 54 53]` is string "1965".
- For the `Amount` field, the value `[49 50 51]` is string "123".
- For the `Price` field, the value `[55 46 53 53]` is string "7.55".

It looks like the `src` argument is the result of `fmt.Print` or something similar if Scanner objects are involved.

I expect to see the `Rows.Scan` produce the same output as `Row.Scan`.

Does anyone know where I went wrong?  Why does the code work with Microsoft SQL Server but not with MySQL?

Comment: This looks like a driver-specific thing. Care to share what drivers you are using for both backends?

Comment: My `go.mod` shows
>    github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql v1.7.1
>    github.com/microsoft/go-mssqldb v1.5.0

Answer (score 0):

I reproduced your issue on mysql 8.0.34 and the `github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql` driver. I also checked that it does not occur in such a simple case with other database engines - in my case postgres 14.x.
Seems like it shouldn't happen, as the documentation for [Row.Scan](https://pkg.go.dev/database/sql#Row.Scan) says scanning works the same as for [Rows.Scan](https://pkg.go.dev/database/sql#Rows.Scan). Confusing indeed.

However, I think your experiment might be irrevelant to the typical usage of `database/sql` API. (More on this below).

You seem to be tinkering with `sql.Scanner` interface to see how it works. You have observed that when receiver gets the `src` argument, it is already instantiated as the value of the right type, or it is just stream of bytes (but the right stream of bytes) when it's called differently. In practice, it doesn't seem to be a problem. First of all, it's not so often that you implement your own `sql.Scanner` for a column. Even if you do, I noticed that there are mysterious cases when I am handed bytes and I need to parse them accordingly. (That happenned to me with my custom types on postgres and it wasn't the difference between `Query` and `QueryRows` - in fact I didn't go deep enough to isolate the difference). I ended up with a type switch, handling both `[]byte` and the concrete type expected, for example:

```
func (d *MyDate) Scan(value any) error {
    switch x := value.(type) {
    case time.Time:
        // convert from timestamp...
        return nil
    case []byte:
        // parse ...
    default:
        return fmt.Errorf("scan date: unknown type %T", x)
    }
}
```

You might use the same strategy when implementing column scanner for your own type. The point is, are you going to do that..

Please keep in mind that you usually just `Scan` into your struct fields without thinking about custom scans. Here, the code below works for both `Row.Scan` and `Rows.Scan`:

```
type Fruit struct {
    Id     int
    Name   string
    Year   string
    Amount int
    Price  float64
}

func run() (err error) {

    var x Fruit

    fmt.Println("query 1 row:")
    row := db.QueryRow("select * from fruits where id=?", 1)
    err = row.Scan(&x.Id, &x.Name, &x.Year, &x.Amount, &x.Price)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    fmt.Printf("%+v\n", x)

    fmt.Println("query rows:")
    rows, err := db.Query("select * from fruits;")
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer rows.Close()
    for rows.Next() {
        err = rows.Scan(&x.Id, &x.Name, &x.Year, &x.Amount, &x.Price)
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
        fmt.Printf("%+v\n", x)
    }
    return rows.Err()
}
```

results in:

```
query 1 row:
{Id:1 Name:bobofrut Year:2023 Amount:100 Price:3.14}
query rows:
{Id:1 Name:bobofrut Year:2023 Amount:100 Price:3.14}
```

Hope this helps!

PS1. Please note I used some simplification by having `Year` as string. In reality it can be a variety of types, a custom date, `time.Time` truncated to the year, or so. It didn't seem relevant to your case.

PS2. You've probably heard that storing currency as float is a terrible idea - please use mysql DECIMAL(M,2) and on Go side something like [shopspring/decimal](https://github.com/shopspring/decimal).

PS3. Your `fmt.Printf` in `Scan` implementation had a small bug with regard to the numbering of format args, it should be `... type=%[2]T value=%[2]v` for the two args given. I guess you simply mis-pasted code from some other moment of your coding.

Comment: I am no longer tinkering with `sql.Scanner`.  I have a **working** object relation mapper except it doesn't work with the MySQL backend.  My ORM takes in all kinds of struct and uses the `reflect` package to generate the list of scanners for the variadic `args` argument of `Rows.Scan`  The scaanner code is complicated enough that I don't want to clutter it with type switches.  Anyway, that approach is fixing the symptoms, not the cause.

Comment: Then it's better to file a bug report to the author of the driver. Btw, there is nothing wrong with tinkering.